# SQL get count of rows between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

Let's say I have this table.

```
Id CId Date
1  1   2020-12-25 08:44:04.247
2  2   2020-12-25 08:44:04.566
3  2   2020-12-25 08:44:04.111
```

I want to get CIDs which have more than one value with the same Date, hour, minutes and seconds ( we should ignore milliseconds)

For example, in this case I want to get the CId = 2:

Or I want to get results like this

```
CId CountWIthSameDate  Date
1    1                 2020-12-25 08:44:04
2    2                 2020-12-25 08:44:04
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions and round the date to the nearest second:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by dateadd(second, datediff(second, t.date, 0)) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

This returns the original rows with the duplicates, rather than the counts.

If you just want the results as an aggregation:

```
select cid, dateadd(second, datediff(second, t.date, 0) as date,
       count(*)
from t
group by cid,
         dateadd(second, datediff(second, t.date, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

```
SELECT Cid, Count(1) CountWIthSameDate, Format([Date], 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') [Date] FROM TableName Group By Cid, Format([Date], 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')
```